# Updated: Javascript Video Fade in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Update: This works perfectly in Safari but does the action detailed in the original post below in Chrome - any suggestions.

I am using the following video which should fade up on mouse click, the control visibility fades up without issue but the video is on or off (opacity 0 or 1 - all or nothing). Any help appreciated in connecting the video content to the fade, not just the controls - (for the sake of consistency in pure Javascript if possible).

```js
function assets() {
  "use strict";
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  elem.style.transition = "opacity 8s linear 0s";
  elem.style.opacity = 1.0;
  elem.play();
}
```

```css
video {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="assets()">video</a>
<br>

<video width="200px" height="200px" controls>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to toggle the opacity, try something along the lines of:

```
elem.style.opacity = Math.abs(elem.style.opacity - 1);
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking I would amend this to the last line of the JS, with the earlier remaining the same?